# Prime factor product

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

Let $P$ be the product of all prime factors $k$ and $P_d$ equal to the product of all exact dividers of $P$. Calculate or value of $x$, know that $P_d$ is equal to the product of all exact dividers of $P$. Calculate or value of $x$, know that $P_d$ is equal to $P ^ x$ . (Exact dividers: And that they all divide the number equally and that the division is exact).

I do not know, can not produce much, but I found the formula for calculating the product of dividers of a natural number:
where $a ^ k \cdot b ^ y \cdot c ^ z \cdot  ....  \cdot n ^ p$ prime factors of a number. Formula: $\sqrt (a ^ k \cdot b ^ y \cdot c ^ z \cdot ... \cdot n ^ p) ^ {(k + 1) (y + 1) (z + 1) .... (p + 1)}$

Formula of the book: ''Praticando aritmética, de Jose Carlos Admo Lacerda ''

Comment: The problem statement is somewhat unclear ...

Comment: is $x=k$ ? only way I think of it.

Comment: Why would that be?

Comment: "prime factors $k$" means "prime factors of $k$"? And what does the "exact" in "exact dividers" (I assume divisors) mean?

Comment: I think this means if $N=12 = 2^2*3$ then $P= 2*3=6$ and $P_d = 1*2*3*4*6*12=1728$ and $1728= 2^6*3^3$.  So $P_d = N^3$ and $x = 3$.  Then texts value for $P_d$ says that $P_d = \sqrt{2^2*3}^{(2+1)(1+1)}$... which is does.

Comment: '' exact dividers '' was what was written in the book cited

Comment: It's not fair of us to judge you on your english, but unfortunately, your sentences are *very* hard to understand.  I'm not sure what we can do about it.  But that might explain why people are having a hard time with the question.

Comment: Exact dividers: And that they all divide the number equally and that the division is exact.

Comment: "'' exact dividers '' was what was written in the book cited"  Which wasn't written in English.  If I understand the question clearly, I think in English we would say:  "factors" or "divisors"

Comment: You may be thinking it was a mistake in my English, but I didn't understand when it was written....

Comment: Oops  I was mistake about $x$.  $x$ is such that $P_d = P^x$ and not $N^x$.  In general there is no such $x$ but if you asked to do this for $N=2^{k-1}$ there is.

Comment: Good! But you started from an answer, below you proved how to get to her? (x = 2 ^ (k-1))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are told to do this for $N= 2^{k-1}$ this is easy.

$P$= product of prime factors:  $2^{k-1}$ has only $2$ as a prime factor.  So $P= 2$.

$P_d$ = product of all factors.  The factors of $2^{k-1}$ are: $1,2,4,8,.....,2^{k-1}$.  SO $P_d = 1*2*4*8*....*2^{k-1} = 2^0*2^1*2^2*2^3*....*2^{k-1} = 2^{0+1+2+3+....+k-1} = 2^{\frac {(k-1)k}2}$

And if $P_d = P^x$ then $P_d= 2^{\frac {(k-1)k}2}=2^x$ so $x = \frac {(k-1)k}2$.

To do this in general (a *much* harder problem), read on....

=======

Maybe do an example.

$N = 2^4*3^3*5^2$

$P = 2*3*5$ and that will be easy for any $N$ with prime factorization with $N=\prod p_i^{a_i}$ then$P = \prod p_i$.

Now the factors of $N$ are $2^a3^b5^c$ where $0\le a\le 4$ and $0\le b \le 3$ and $0 \le c \le 2$.

Now what is $P_d$.  Well clearly $P_d = 2^{M_2}3^{M_3}5^{m_5}$ for some powers of $M_2, M_3, M_5$ but how do we calculate what $M_2, M_3, M_5$ are?

Well we have that $M_2$ is some sum of all the possible $a$s but how?  But for every fixed factor $3^b5^c$ will have the factors $2^0*3^b5^c$ and $2^1*3^b5^c$ and $2^2*3^b5^c$.... $2^5*3^b5^c$.  That is the factors $2^*3^b5^c$ where $b, c$ are fixed.  So for *each* factor $3^b5^c$ we will have $\prod (2^i*(3^b5^c))= 2^{\sum_{i=0}^4i}*(3^b5^c)^6$ and the power of two detrmined be *that* set of factors is $\sum_{i=0}^4i = \frac {4*5}2 =10$.

So the Those factors $2^i$ will contribute ${10}$ toward $M_2$.  Now $b$ can be $0.... 3$, that is $4$ options.  And $c$ can be $0...2$, that is $3$ options.  So there are $4*3=12$ possible $3^b5^c$ and each contribute $10$ toward $M_2$ so $M_2 = 10*12=120$ or $M_2 = (\sum_{i=0}^4 i)(3+1)(2+1)=\frac {4*5}2*(4)(3)$.

Doing the same for $M_3$ and $M_5$ we get $M_3 = (4+1)(2+1)\sum_{i=0}^3i = 5*3*\frac {3*4}2 = 15*6=90$ and $M_5 = (4+1)(3+1)\sum_{i=0}^2i = 5*4*3=60$

So $P_d = 2^{120}3^{90}5^{60}$.

Which happens to be $(2^43^35^2)^{30}=N^{30}$. (Although I do not see why we would have anticipated that $P_d = N^x$ for any integer value of $x.)

And in general:

If $N =\prod p_i^{a_i}$ then $Pd=\prod p_i^{M_{p_i}}= \prod p_i^{(\sum_{k=0}^{a_i} k)\prod_{j\ne i}(a_j +1)} = \prod p_i^{\frac {a_i(a_i + 1)}2*\prod_{j\ne i}(a_j +1)}=$

$\prod p_i^{\frac {a_i}2*p^{a_1+1}\prod_{j\ne i}(a_j +1)}=$

$\prod p_i^{\frac {a_i}2*\prod (a_j+1)}=$

$((\prod p_i^{a_i})^{\frac 12})^{\prod (a_j + 1)} =$

$\sqrt{\prod p_i^{a_i}}^{\prod (a_j + 1)} =$

$\sqrt{N}^{\prod (a_j + 1)}$

Which is your texts answer.

So $P_d = \sqrt{N}^{\prod (a_j + 1)} = N^{\frac 12\prod (a_j + 1)}=N^y$ where $y =\frac 12\prod (a_j + 1)$

But to solve $P_d = P^x$ can't be solved unless $N=\prod p_i^{h}$ where all powers are the same value.

Comment: I just found the feedback here: 2^(k - 1)

Comment: What about $2^{k-1}$?

Comment: I think if you use the formula I put above, maybe you will get that result.

Comment: The problem (as quoted) is how to perform

Comment: Are you saying that your staring number is $2^{k-1}$?  That you want to find the $P$ for $2^{k-1}$ (in which case $P=2$) and $P_d$ for $2^{k-1}$ (in which case $P_d = 1*2*4*8*.....*2^{k-1}$)?  And when $P_d = (2^{k-1})^x$ to solve for $x$?

Comment: I do not know, can not produce much, but I found the formula for calculating the product of dividers of a natural number:
where $a ^ k \cdot b ^ y \cdot c ^ z \cdot  ....  \cdot n ^ p$ prime factors of a number. Formula: $\sqrt (a ^ k \cdot b ^ y \cdot c ^ z \cdot ... \cdot n ^ p) ^ {(k + 1) (y + 1) (z + 1) .... (p + 1)}$

Comment: This is the formula for calculating the product of the dividers of a number, as quoted in the book. You can see her demo in the book if you want: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8bpbu_iUcdvVDVJeWRoZ1FZQ3c/view (page 154)

Comment: So the fourmla says that $P_d = \sqrt{2^{k-1}}^{(k-1+1)}$.